# Undefined columns selected in R script

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I'm getting an error "Undefined columns selected" as these are the valid column name in that particular excel sheet.

```
install.packages("xlsx")
{
  library(xlsx)
  library(readxl)
}
getwd()
Data<- read.xlsx("ABC.xlsx",sheetIndex = 2)
Data<- Data[,c("Profit","Name")]
```

Comment: What does `Data` look like? Please provide `dput(head(Data))`

Comment: 1) You don't nee **`{}`** before and after library statements. 2) `getwd()` is not the best practice, your script will fail when running in session with different working directory than the one where the file is located. Look at `here` package / use `file.path` to construct paths to files.

Answer (score 0):

do a str(Data) to see if column names match your query.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code once

```
  install.packages("xlsx")   
  library(xlsx)

setwd ("path to folder")
getwd()
Data<- read.xlsx("ABC.xlsx",sheetIndex = 2)
Data<- Data[,c("Profit","Name")]
```